# I am a novice JNI,Why doesn't my android jni C ++ try block catch an exception

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I am a novice JNI,Why doesn't my android jni C ++ try block catch an exception,The code crashes when  and the app crashes without jumping to exception handling
this is my code

Activity re code
Receive H264 data with queue at JAVA layer
Start a decoding thread and continuously take a frame of H264 data packets from the queue into the C ++ layer to decode with FFmpeg

```
    class decode extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
//            super.run();
            while (isDecode) {
                byte[] data = one.poll();
                if (data != null)
                    if (ffmpegUtilsInSignalOne != null)
                        ffmpegUtilsInSignalOne.decodeH264One(data);
            }
        }
    }
```

cpp File code

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_cn_zhihuiyun_control_utils_FFMPEGUtils_decodeH264One(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,
                                                          jbyteArray data) {
    if (packetOne != nullptr && pCodecCtxOne != nullptr && vFrameOne != nullptr) {
        if (data == nullptr)
            return;;
        if (isPlay == 0)
            return;
        jbyte *arr = env->GetByteArrayElements(data, JNI_FALSE);
        packetOne->data = (uint8_t *) arr;
        packetOne->size = env->GetArrayLength(data);
        avcodec_send_packet(pCodecCtxOne, packetOne);
        avcodec_receive_frame(pCodecCtxOne, vFrameOne);
        av_packet_unref(packetOne);
        env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(data, arr, 0);
    }
}
```

At this time, a display thread is started in the C layer for screen rendering

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_cn_zhihuiyun_control_utils_FFMPEGUtils_initVisThread(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    isPlay = 1;
    threadVister = pthread_create(&threadVister, nullptr,
                                  reinterpret_cast<void *(*)(void *)>(&showVideo),
                                  (void *) env);
    pthread_detach(threadVister);
}

void *showVideo(JNIEnv *env) {
    try {
        while (isPlay == 1) {
            if (vFrameOne != nullptr && pFrameRGBAOne != nullptr && pCodecCtxOne != nullptr &&
                nativeWindowOne != nullptr) {
                ANativeWindow_lock(nativeWindowOne, &windowBufferOne, nullptr);
                av_image_fill_arrays(pFrameRGBAOne->data, pFrameRGBAOne->linesize,
                                     (const uint8_t *) windowBufferOne.bits, AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA,
                                     detWidth, detHeight, 1);
                int re = -1;
                try {
                    re = libyuv::I420ToARGB(vFrameOne->data[0], vFrameOne->linesize[0],
                                            vFrameOne->data[2], vFrameOne->linesize[2],
                                            vFrameOne->data[1], vFrameOne->linesize[1],
                                            pFrameRGBAOne->data[0], pFrameRGBAOne->linesize[0],
                                            pCodecCtxOne->width, pCodecCtxOne->height);
                    if (env->ExceptionCheck()) {
                        env->ExceptionDescribe();
                        env->ExceptionClear();
                    }
                } catch (...) {

                }
                if (re == -1) {

                } else {
                    ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost(nativeWindowOne);

                }
            }
            }
        }
    } catch (...) {
        printf("error");

    }
    if (vFrameOne != nullptr) {
        av_frame_free(&vFrameOne);
        vFrameOne = nullptr;
    }
    if (packetOne != nullptr) {
        av_free(packetOne);
        packetOne = nullptr;
    }
    if (pFrameRGBAOne != nullptr) {
        av_free(pFrameRGBAOne);
        pFrameRGBAOne = nullptr;
    }
    if (pCodecCtxOne != nullptr) {
        avcodec_free_context(&pCodecCtxOne);
        pCodecCtxOne = nullptr;
    }
    if (nativeWindowOne != nullptr) {
        ANativeWindow_release(nativeWindowOne);
        nativeWindowOne = nullptr;
    }

    pthread_exit(&threadVister);
}
```

Comment: Because a C++ SIGSEGV is not a Java exception, and if it was you would be clearing it by calling `env->ExceptionClear()`. It isn't a C++ exception either.

Comment: I am implementing a yuvToRGBA. When the data I pass in is not a frame. May cause abnormal crash. I tried adding Try but just like my code test above, no exception was caught. Then the program collapsed. How should I catch this exception and throw the exception to not crash the program?

Comment: And have you considered debugging your code? Testing for null pointers before you dereference them? You shouldn't be trying to catch null pointer exceptions even in Java where they exist, let alone C++ where they don't.

Comment: As I said, I am a novice JNI. I am not familiar with this thing. I know that there are JAVA exceptions and C ++, which are two different exceptions. C ++ can only catch exceptions that belong to C ++. But when I transfer data from JAVA layer to C ++ layer to call C ++ function processing, if the process of calling C ++ function raises an exception, shouldn't the exception belong to C ++ layer at this time? But the C ++ try block cannot catch the exception caused by calling this function. I can't understand this

Comment: The null pointer deference is not an exception in C++. Stated now for the third time. You have to defend against it, not catch it afterwards.

Comment: No, no, no null pointer exception. The parameters that need to be passed are judged not to be empty. The data should be incomplete. It is common to lose packets because of the UDP protocol. This is a small probability. If I don't transfer a complete frame of pictures into it for processing, it will report a memory address error. I can't tell if the packet is absolutely complete. So I can only find a way to catch this exception and clear it. To ensure that the next frame can be decoded and displayed instead of crashing. I use try block.

Comment: But unable to capture, this problem has troubled me for a long time, I don't know how to solve it. thank you for your reply.

Comment: What you just explained in the comments should be an edit to your question. Your underlying question seems to be "how do I determine that I have received enough 'frame data' to ensure that my C++ code does not crash". so tell us what a frame looks like, how it is filled in by UDP packets, and what your code does with a full frame. The solution to your problem is in determining if a frame is complete rather than "catch a crash and continue"

Comment: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo019 - or, with small description here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-019/

Comment: You've posted a question about dereferencing a null pointer. If that isn't your question, you are wasting time. I don't care about yours, but mine is valuable. And I've told you how to solve that question. Several times. Listen. Being a novice is fine, we were all novices once, but it doesn't imply that you should have to be told everything three times, or that you get to restate your original question three times instead of trying to learn from what you're told.

Comment: @Botje  I have re-edited the question.

Comment: Sigh. If the code crashes with a SIGSEGV due to dereferencing a null pointer, I have now addressed that, and why it doesn't result in an exception, about six times. If it crashes with some other problem, you haven't stated what it was, so nobody can answer you. And if we aren't supposed to point out where your code is wrong this entire site would be quite pointless.

Comment: Yes. I know you have pointed out the problem with my code. It may be that my English level is not enough. I can't express exactly what I want to express. I mean why C ++ can't try to get an exception. The previous code was written deliberately for testing. I want to clearly understand why C ++ cannot try to get an exception. Thank you

Comment: There is no such thing as a `NullPointerException` in C++. A null pointer dereference results in a SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) signal being sent to your process. You cannot catch that with a try-catch, only with a signal handler (see the `signal` function, if you must). Ignoring segmentation faults will quickly reduce your program state to random garbage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should carefully read the [documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.4/group__lavc__decoding.html#ga11e6542c4e66d3028668788a1a74217c) of `avcodec_receive_frame`:

> Return decoded output data from a decoder.
>   Parameters
>      avctx  codec context
>      frame  This will be set to a reference-counted video or audio frame (depending on the decoder type) allocated by the decoder. **Note that the function will always call av_frame_unref(frame) before doing anything else.**
>
> Returns
>      0: success, a frame was returned
>      **AVERROR(EAGAIN): output is not available in this state - user must try to send new input**
>      AVERROR_EOF: the decoder has been fully flushed, and there will be no more output frames
>      AVERROR(EINVAL): codec not opened, or it is an encoder other negative values: legitimate decoding errors

I have highlighted two key pieces of information:

- First, the call to `avcodec_receive_frame` will invalidate `vFrameOne`. If your other thread is in the middle of decoding, your program will crash. You will need to establish a synchronization mechanism between receiving and displaying threads to make sure the receiver is always receiving into a frame only it has access to, and that it only passes full frames to the displaying side. (see next point)
- Second, you should check the return value of `avcodec_receive_frame`. If you see an `AVERROR(EAGAIN)` you have not received enough packets to produce a full frame. Only if this function produces 0 can you take the full frame and hand it over to the displaying thread.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I get it. This can be handled with a queue. If it returns 0, it will enter the queue. The display thread continuously decodes the queue data and displays it. Make sure it is a complete frame.